# Filter an Object based on values in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, ecmascript-6

I encountered a small problem, that I can't figure out or find a solution to, on the internet, at least that I'm aware of. I want to filter an object in javascript, based on a undefined number of values in an array. I have an object like this:

```
categories = { "category1: {"_id": "1234"}, "category2: {"_id": "4567"}, ... };
```

I also have an array including values of IDs, like so:

```
catArray = ["1234", "4567", ... ]
```

Now I want to filter all categories out of the category-Object, matching the IDs from the array. I managed to filter the category for a single array-value, but not for all. It's working like this:

```
const categoriesFilter = categories.filter(cat => {
        return cat._id == catArray[0];
});
```

So far it is working. But now I want to match the categories from all possible ID-values from the array. I tried to do it with a for-loop, but it's not working out. Any idea? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: That *shouldn’t* be working, since you said `categories` was a plain object. Those don’t have `filter`. Is `categories` actually an array?

Comment: It shouldn't be working another way: `_id` doesn't match the data either which has `id`.

Comment: Maybe i switched the category. I got it from some other code and it is working, i just put that object above as an example.
And the ID was a mistake. It should be "_id"

Answer (score 1):

Categories should be an array of objects, for example. Then you can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
let categories = [{ "id": "1234" }, { "id": "4567" }];
let catArray = ["1234", "45674"];

const categoriesFilter = categories.filter(cat => {
  return catArray.includes(cat.id);
});

console.log(categoriesFilter);
```

Comment: That isn't a valid array.

Comment: It isn't, you're supposed to fill the ... with other elements.

Comment: No. You still have object keys in there. `category1` for example.

Comment: You're right. Sorry, didn't pay attention. Edited the answer.

Comment: Just added a snippet to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could first create one object with `id` as keys and then use it as lookup table to create new object with filtered properties by array.

```js
const cat = { category1: {"id": "1234"}, category2: {"id": "4567"}, category3: {"id": "123"}};
const arr = ["1234", "4567" ]
const hash = Object.entries(cat)
  .reduce((r, [k, v]) => Object.assign(r, {[v.id]: {[k]: v}}), {})

const result = arr.reduce((r, id) => {
  if(hash[id]) Object.assign(r, hash[id])
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do :

`var categories = { "category1": {"id": "1234"}, "category2": {"id": "4567"}, "category4": {"id": "45678"}};
var catArray = ["1234", "4567"];
var categoriesFilter = Object.entries(categories).filter(([catKey,catValue]) => { return catArray.includes(catValue.id); });`

Comment: that worked half way. I can iterate now trough the IDs from the array. But all the other keys and values from the categories objects got lost.

Answer (score 0):

```
const categories = { category1: {"id": "1234"}, category2: {"id": "4567"}, category3: {"id": "123"}};
const catArray = ["1234", "4567" ]
const checkIfArrIncludes = (id) => catArray.includes(id);
const matchedCats = Object.values(categories).filter(cat => (checkIfArrIncludes(cat.id) ? cat : 0));
```